# Реализация сворачивания/разворачивания текста с тегами

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как сделать сворачивание и разворачивание блока с тегами p внутри? Например:

```html
<div class=container>
  <p> Привет это Вася </p>
  <p> Новое сообщение</p>
  <p>Может и нет</p>
  <p>Может и да</p>
  <p>Может и нет и да</p>
  <button class="show">
    Показать
  </button>
</div>
```

Пытался через `jquery`:

```js
$('.show').click(function(){
  $(this).parent().find('.hidden').slideToggle(300);
})
```

В `span` с классом `.hidden` помещаешь текст, который хочешь сворачивать.

Answer (score 2):

```js
$('.show').click(function() {
  $(this).parent().find('.hidden').slideToggle(300);
})
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <p> Привет это Вася </p>
  <p> Новое сообщение</p>
  <button class="show">Показать</button>
  <div class="hidden">
    <p>Может и нет</p>
    <p>Может и да</p>
    <p>Может и нет и да</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Мне нужно не весь скрывать ,а только часть

Answer (score 0):

Это делается с помощью тэга `<details>`.

```css
details{ margin-left: 10px; }
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>Показать</summary>
  <p>Текст</p>
  <details>
    <summary>Показать</summary>
    <p>Текст</p>
    <p>Текст</p>
  </details>
  <p>Текст</p>
  <p>Текст</p>
</details>
```